# Angular 2 + Spring MVC CrossOrigin Session managment

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, session

I making a call from Angular 2 component to Spring MVC controller

```
let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    console.log('fromDate',startDate,endDate);
    params.set('fromDate',startDate);
    params.set('toDate',endDate);
    params.set('env',environmentValue);


   return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/`,{search:params}).map(/*customcode*/)
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String methodCall(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam String env, @RequestParam String fromDate,
            @RequestParam String toDate)  {

        List<WorkaroundDataBean> searchResult = this.delegate
                .getData(env);
        if (null != request.getSession().getAttribute("waData")) {
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("waData");
        }
        request.getSession().setAttribute("waData", searchResult);
        try {
            return this.mapper.writeValueAsString(searchResult);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        }
    }
```

When i call this controller for first time it saves the data in session, when i call it again the second time

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("waData")
```

returns null

Can someone suggest what can be the issue, angular is running on 4200 and controller on 8080 locally

Comment: Don't use `angularjs` tag while asking angular2 or 4 question?

Comment: Doesnt look like a CSRF or CORS issue. if it is, then the first request would not even reach your controller.. Looks like a new session is getting created for each request,. have you setup any security filter to manage session?

Comment: No i have used nothing, whereas the first request is concerned i am using CORS chrome extension